# Xamarin warning : max res 25, skipping mipmap-anydpi-v26

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have configured Visual Studio 2017 to build an app, but during compile I see this warning:

> xamarine warning : max res 25, skipping mipmap-anydpi-v26

and if I try to create a new Android device, to test the application, I see this result:

> Device could not be created Please file an issue by choosing Report a
>   Problem in the Help menu...

How can I solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: Hello, have you solved your question?

Comment: I also get the same two errors

Answer (score 1):

please remove Resources/mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder
Then error would be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need change your `targetSdkVersion` to 26(or 27 ), because this `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder will be used on the devices which version is >=26.

Also you can read [what is `mipmap-anydpi-v26`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080712/whats-mipmap-anydpi-v26-in-res-directory-in-android-studio-3-0)

If your `targetSdkVersion` is <26, like @Andrei has said, you need delete `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder.