# Is still in new generation Google App Bundle need mdpi or xdpi resource files?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

> In this year Google annoucement new app bunle for android or Google
>   Play users.

Good, but already know it we are using still xdpi, mdpi, xxdpi, resource files.

So, app bundle split your images, language but if we delete xdpi, mdpi, xxdpi files and we protect xxxdpi resource files and we reduced %40 app size.

I mean if you delete other resource images (in res folder) except xxxdpi, 
will the app bundle be a problem for devices?

Comment: From what i have seen it prefers xml vector assets for anydpi. Just like the icons gemerated by using image asset generator.

Comment: @ZainAftab good but I don't get it. how detect if we using vector asset which dpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide only the images in the `xxxhdpi` density, your app will run slower on some devices since the Android platform will need to scale down the images on the fly before rendering them. It also takes CPU thus to perform the scaling, thus taking on the battery of the users.

So although this is an option that is perfectly compatible with the Android App Bundle (nothing will crash -- all the users will get your xxxhdpi resources), it will have negative consequences for your users, so you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

`**anydpi**:` These resources take precedence in any dpi. So even if you have `mipmap-hdpi` or `mipmap-mdpi` matching with current devices density, resource from `mipmap-anydpi` will always be picked up.

I have been using it for adaptive launcher icon for my apps and it generates the xml and there is no need for any other dpi dependent drawables.

You can get more​ information by visiting these links.

- [Anydpi and anydpi-v26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080712/whats-mipmap-anydpi-v26-in-res-directory-in-android-studio-3-0)
- [Image asset studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.)
- [nodpi vs anydpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156957/what-is-the-difference-between-anydpi-and-nodpi)
- [Adaptive icons and more](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/adaptive-icons/)

Couldn't put in comment so adding it here