# Why use both legacy image launcher icons and adaptive icons

Tags: android

In our app, we have two sets of launcher icons, one for recent devices (from API 26), and one for older devices (just showing mdpi here, but we have other dpi folders as well):

[image]

The API26 ones use the newer adaptive-icons in a single folder `mipmap-anydpi-v26`, while the pre-API26 use images (webp) in several folders: `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi` etc.

The API26 set of icons is much better since a single set of icons supports all densities.
However, since our app supports devices back to API21, we need the older icons as well.

So what I'm wondering is: Is there any point of having the newer icons mipmap-anydpi-v26, since the older ones in mipmap-*dpi folder would support both newer and older devices?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080712/whats-mipmap-anydpi-v26-in-res-directory-in-android-studio-3-0

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to answer the question, which is: what is the point of having both pre API26 and post API26 since pre API26 icons can be used for all

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the old-style icons on devices that support adaptive icons then they will be scaled down to fit in a smaller safe foreground area.  This will typically appear as a square inside a white circular border.  If you don't want the extra border then you need to include the new-style icons as well.