# minSdkVersion 26 or later and just with mipmap-anydpi containing ic_launcher icons

Tags: android, android-min-sdk, android-mipmap

I wonder, when my new project is `minSdkVersion 26` (or later), that I can safely delete these `mipmap-*dpi` folders and their content `ic_launcher` icons, and then simply with `mipmap-anydpi` (renamed from `mipmap-anydpi-v26`) folder containing vector icons (`ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml`).

[image: Android Studio screen shot]

It seems no problem to build a such project. Are there any potential problem I don't aware with this?

Answer (score 1):

Event though it builds without issues, there seems to be a difference. I just did the same—upgrade the `minSdkVersion` to 26, then rename the folders to drop `-v26`. Afterwards, the app icon looked different on the same Android 12 device I had used before to test the old behaviour.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080712/whats-mipmap-anydpi-v26-in-res-directory-in-android-studio-3-0#comment120894612_51171266) supports that observation.