# How can I create app icon when I use Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have read the articles about creating app icon, such as [What's mipmap-anydpi-v26 in res directory in Android Studio 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080712/whats-mipmap-anydpi-v26-in-res-directory-in-android-studio-3-0) and [Create app icons with Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-adaptive).

When I create a project with latest Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1, the wizard of Android Studio will generate the default app icon automatically.

I know I can use *Image Asset Studio* to create myself app icon, so I select a file .svg file and try to generate it, you can see Image 1, and Image 2

When I check these generated icons, I found the extension name of my files is `.png`, but the the extension name of files which is generated by the wizard is `.webp`, you can see Image 3.

I don't know if there is new way to create app icon, could you tell me ?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

**Image 3**

[image]

Comment: "When I check these generated icons, I found the extension name of my files is .png, but the the extension name of files which is generated by the wizard is .webp, you can see Image 3." -- so? What is the problem? "I don't know if there is new way to create app icon, could you tell me?" -- there is no new way. "the wizard of Android Studio will generate the default app icon automatically" -- Studio copies WebP files in this case. That is their choice. Their wizard generates PNGs. That too is their choice. Android can handle either (though WebP will have some limits on backwards compatibility).

Comment: @HelloCW change the name of your icons to the android default icon and delete android's default icon. for example, change from `new.png` to `ic_launcher.png` and delete `ic_launcher.webp` icon. Your new icon will automatically appear when you run your app. Let me know if you have any confusion.